# How to setup keycloak to join existing network in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

How to setup `keycloak` to join the existing network in docker-compose

I am using the following yml file. Please guide

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:  
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      container_name: arc-jboss-keycloak
      networks:
        - arc-net
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: <db_host_ip> 
        DB_PORT: 20000
        DB_DATABASE: jboss-keycloak
        DB_USER: admin
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: admin
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
        KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
        ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      ports:
        - 20001:8080
        #- 8443:8443
      #depends_on:
      #  - postgres
networks:
  arc-net:
    external:
        name:arc-net
```

I want to join existing `arc-net` network

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you tell us what sort of problem you're experiencing? That configuration looks correct to attach your keycloak instance to the `arc-net` Docker network (except that you're using an outdated keycloak image; current images can be found at https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak, **not** on docker hub).

Comment: @larsks actually it is not using the existing arc-net network, but creating a new network. 

Regarding the older version, yes. Actually, here I am trying various options to understand the various configuration and get hands-on docker

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
networks:
  arc-net:
    external: true
```

This should work :)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?